# how to check when stack is empty

Tags: java, stack

well this is my array stack separated from my main
i have just one problem though, my code have no problems yet it lacks
something like if i run pop yet the stack is empty, it must have a dialog saying that it is empty, i tried an if else statement yet i dont know where to put it or is it really the if else statement needed, anyways here's my code. . .

```
public class ArrayStack {
        int STACK_MAX = 20;
        int size = -1 ;
        int top = -1 ;
        int StackObj[] = new int[STACK_MAX];

          /**************** for PUSH METHOD *********/

        public void Push(int obj) {
            if (size()==STACK_MAX){
                System.out.println("STACK is FULL");
                }
            else{
                    StackObj[++top]= obj;
                }
        } 

        /**************** for SIZE Method ********/

        public int size() {
            return (top+1);    
        }

      /******************** for Display Method****/

        public void DisplayStack() {
                String disp="";

                for (int i=top; i>=0; i--){
                    disp += StackObj[i] + "\n";                     
                }
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Elements of the Stacks : \n" + disp);
            }

      /***************** for isEmpty Method *******/

      public boolean isEmpty(){

        return (top == -1);

      }

      /***************** for Top Method ***********/
        public int Topmethod(){

        int taas = StackObj[top];

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Top is : "+taas);
        return (top);
        }

      /***************** for Pop Method ***********/       
           public int pop(){

            int topItem = StackObj[top];
               top--;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The recently pushed number was Deleted: "+topItem);
          return(top);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your title to make it more relevant to your actual problem? Also in editor there is `{}` option which allows you to post code examples properly.

Comment: Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: `if ( isEmpty() ) { JOptionPane.showMessage(); }` throw that in the pop method.

Comment: sorry my bad ^_^ thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add something in your pop method to handle recognizing when the stack was empty then handling the case of an empty stack such as:

```
public int pop(){
    if(size() == 0){  //detect empty stack
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("my frame");; //handle empty stack
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Stack is empty!");
        return null; //make sure you handle a null return value if you use this
    }
    int topItem = StackObj[top];
       top--;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The recently pushed number was Deleted: "+topItem);
  return(top);


}
```

Comment: Change your `system.out` to a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` and you'll have exactly what he's looking for imo.

Comment: oh sorry didn't see he asked to pop a dialogue, thanks- edited now

Comment: Thanks peggy i changed it though coz im not using a frame. . . it goes like this

Answer (score 0):

here i edited it

```
public int pop(){
    if(size() == 0){  //detect empty stack
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Stack is empty!");
    return (top); //make sure you handle a null return value if you use this
}
    int topItem = StackObj[top];
       top--;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The recently pushed number was Deleted: "+topItem);
  return(top);


}
```